# How to open folds in a pedit-preview popup window?

Tags: vimscript, popup-menu, previewwindow

I'm displaying a file contents by using `:pedit …the-file-path…`, to then call `popup_setoptions(…the-ID…,#{firstline:anumber})` in order to scroll the popup and highlight/show the desired part of the file.

There's however one problem — the folds are closed by default and thus they **hide** the file contents… How to open them?

What I've tried is a `exe ':'.pupid.'windo norm! zi'` however the command fails upfront with and 'Invalid range` error. The pupid is being obtained via popup_findpreview() and is correct.

Comment: you can possibly use `:pedit +set\ nofoldenable <file>`.

Comment: Can confirm that `:pedit +set\ nofoldenable <file>` works too; IMO, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Would you post it as an answer please?

Comment: @filbranden thanks done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I've tried is a exe ':'.pupid.'windo norm! zi' however the command fails upfront with and 'Invalid range` error. The pupid is being obtained via popup_findpreview() and is correct.

That's because [`popup_findpreview()`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_findpreview()) gives you a window *ID*, but the range passed to [`:windo`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#:windo) expects window *numbers*:

> :[range]windo {cmd}   Execute {cmd} in each window or if [range] is given
> only in windows for which the **window number** lies in
> the [range].  It works like doing this: >

Try to use [`win_execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#win_execute()) instead of `:windo`:

```
call win_execute(pupid, 'norm! zi')
```

The latter is better anyway, because it has fewer side-effects.

Comment: It works! I've had to use `zR` instead of `zi`, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the help for the [:pedit](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#:pedit) command, you will see this:

```
                                                    :ped :pedit
:ped[it][!] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
            Edit {file} in the preview window.  The preview window is
            opened like with :ptag.  The current window and cursor
            position isn't changed.  Useful example: 
                    :pedit +/fputc /usr/include/stdio.h
```

Note that you can use the `+cmd` command to execute an additional command when opening the preview window. In your case, you can open the file and disallowing folding by using this command then:

```
:pedit +setl\ nofoldenable <file>
```

Note that you need to escape the whitespace between the `:setl` and the actual option value. You can probably also add an additional command to scroll to the required line, e.g. something like this:

```
:pedit +setl\ nofoldenable|44 <file>
```

It should open `<file>`, disable folding in that window and jump to line `44`.